# What is a two-way adapter pattern

Tags: design-patterns

In the book Design Patterns by GoF (Eric Gamma and others), two-way adapter pattern is mentioned which is used for transparency. They are useful when 2 different clients want to view the same object differently. Could some one give a C++ example for the same and in which practical scenarios it can be used ??

Comment: :) no no ..It is not a homework, I am preparing for an interview and though I understand the adapter pattern, I did not understand two-way adapter usage. I mentioned C++ because the examples in this book are in Smalltalk which I am not aware of.

Comment: But the examples in the book are all in C++ or Smalltalk.  Why not just look at the code given by GoF?  Or was that one given in Smalltalk?  Sorry, I don't have my text here to check.

Comment: In the book the example is only about the normal adapter patterns - class adapter or object adapter. Two-way adapters are different than these I guess.

Answer (score 4):

The Two-Ways Adapters are adapters that implements both interfaces of Target and Adaptee. The adapted object can be used as Target in new systems dealing with Target classes or as Adaptee in other systems dealing with Adaptee classes. Going further on this line of thinking, we can have adapters implementing n interfaces, adapting to n systems. Two-way adapters and n-way adapters are hard to implement in systems not supporting multiple inheritance. If adapter has to extend the Target class it can not extent another class like Adaptee, so the Adaptee should be an interface and all the calls should be delegated from the adapter to the Adaptee object.

[image: Adapter Design Pattern]

Source: http://www.oodesign.com/adapter-pattern.html

Answer (score 3):

I find that the explanation given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596527730-01-04.aspx) is quite good. It is a C# example but the explanation is clear and the example can quite easily be translated into C++ code. The example is also quite detailed.

Comment: Alright, so the only difference between a two-way adapter and a classic class adapter is : 1) the classic class adapter can be accessed via the Itarget/client interface alone 2) two-way adapter can be accessed the via the Itarget/class interface as well as the adaptee interface

Answer (score 0):

As Go4 explains (page 143 for me), it is an extension of Adapter to multiple inheritance.  Instead of extending one interface type, the adapter class extends two.